# GeoTools in java Application without using Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, geotools

Is it possible to use [geotools](http://www.geotools.org/) in a Java application without using Maven? I downloaded a stable version but I don't see how to import it as a library in Netbeans. I have it as many jar files.

Comment: It may have been stupid, but I've used a subset of GeoTools and just added the jars I needed. Wasn't exactly easy, but you only have to do it once.

Comment: Have a look on this tutorial: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/quickstart/netbeans.html#maven-alternative

Comment: thx i must have looked over it!